# Need Assistance with a RegEx in .NET

Tags: .net, regex

In .NET, I am trying to match a pattern like this:

```
("any character in here as long as one or more forward slashes / is also in here//")
```

So:

- Open Paren
- Double-Quote
- any character as long as there is at least one forward slash included
- Double-Quote
- Close Paren

Examples:

- TEST:"blah" → not a match
- TEST:("blah") → not a match
- TEST:"blah//blah too" → not a match
- TEST:(blah) → not a match
- TEST:"blah/blah too" → not a match
- TEST:("blah//BLAH too") → **MATCH**
- TEST:("Blah/blah too") → **MATCH**
- TEST:("//blah/blah-Another blah") → **MATCH**
- TEST:("blah blah blah-anotherblah//") → **MATCH**

I tried this:

```
public const String myRegEx = "\\(\"[^)\\n\\r\\t](.*)[\\/]+(.*)\"\\)";
Regex forwardSlashesRegEx = new Regex(myRegEx);
if(forwardSlashesRegEx.IsMatch(mystring)){
    // do something ...
}
```

But it seems to be picking up on other parts of the string that are not matches as well.

There can be more than one instance of these patterns in the string, but I do not need to match every instance, I just need to see if at least one instance of the pattern is within the string.

Comment: What about `("/")`? should that match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET you might write the pattern like:

```
const String myRegEx = @"\(""[^/""]*/[^""]*""\)";
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n0j7Ev/1) and a [.NET demo](https://ideone.com/vSTE8e).

Or with escaped backslashes:

```
const String myRegEx = "\\(\"[^/\"]*/[^\"]*\"\\)";
```

The pattern matches:

- `\\(\"` Match `("`
- `[^/\"]*` Match chars other than `/` or `"` (your could add `\\n\\r\\t` as well if you don't want to cross matching newlines and tabs)
- `/` Match literally
- `[^\"]*` Match chars other than `"`
- `\"\\)` Match `")`

Example code:

```
string mystring = "...";
const String myRegEx = "\\(\"[^/\"]*/[^\"]*\"\\)";
Regex forwardSlashesRegEx = new Regex(myRegEx);

if(forwardSlashesRegEx.IsMatch(mystring)){
    // do something
}
```

Comment: You only need to double double quotes inside verbatim string literals. OP is using a regular string literal.

Comment: I added more clarification to my original post, if you wouldn't mind taking another quick look. For your suggestion would it be like this: `myregex = "\(\"\"[^/\"\"]*/[^\"\"]*\"\"\)"` or like this: `myregex = @"\(\"\"[^/\"\"]*/[^\"\"]*\"\"\)"`, or something entirely different?

Comment: @Brian I have added the regex with the code as an example.